# PHP + Wordpress: Auto list image name into dropdown slection

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am creating wordpress theme option panel and want to use some icons. I have one directory dedicated for icon into my theme folder. What I want to do is if user add any new image into that folder it will automatic appear into dropdown selection list into theme option panel.

Is there any way to do this in PHP with Wordpress? I believe that is possible as I saw one theme has the same option but it was so complex so couldn't figured out that and don't remember theme name too now.

I have to use it with below type of code

```
$video_tax = array(-1 => 'Choose a category');
$video_terms = get_terms('video_category');
if ($video_terms) {
    foreach ($video_terms as $video_term) {
        $video_tax[$video_term->term_id] = $video_term->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to start by having a look at [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). This will list all the contents of a folder on your system. From there it would just be a matter of putting the correct path, url or whatever you want in the the value of your options.

EDIT: Here's some sample code from one of my plugins:

```
function icons_meta(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $link = $custom["icon"][0];
    $files = scandir(PATH."/icons");
    $selected = '';

    echo "<select name='icon'>";
    foreach($files as $file){
        if($file == $link){ 
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        } else {
            $selected = '';
        }
        echo "<option value='$file' $selected>".$file."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: I am trying but I want it into array with foreach. Can you please learn me how to do that?

Comment: Please check my main question I have added example code I am looking for.

Comment: Issue Solved. Thanks little brief, if some one want to use. Actually your answer give me a path to work on. However I couldn't understood how to use for my work. Thank found post into one forum and implemented into my structure and its done. working fine. I had to use foreach to get file name as array. Thanks again to give me such direction, it helped lot lot lot.